# I can't inlcude autoload.php file in my home.php file?

Tags: php, composer-php, require, vendor

I can't inlcude autoload.php file in my home.php file. Any help please ?[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk5ol.png)

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

your path starts with a `/`, which means it's an **absolute** path, not a relative one. get rid of it and it'll work.

and for your next question: *code does not belong in screenshots or on external platforms* - include it in your *question*.